# Simulating paths of stochastic process from density

Tags: r, probability, simulation, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I need yout help! I have a stochastic process $X_t$ and I know its density function $f(x,t)$, which is defined for $x>t$.
I'm looking for a code in R that simulates the paths of the process, so I want to plot $(t,X_t)$.

For example, for the Brownian motion we have (page 10 http://www.math.chalmers.se/Stat/Grundutb/CTH/tms150/1819/lab06.pdf)

```
n <- 1000
x <- seq(0,1,by=1/n)
y <- c(0,cumsum(rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=sqrt(1/n))))
plot(x,y, type='l')
```

Now I don't have the normal density, and not even one of the other "famous" densities, but my function $f$ for $x>t$. Do you have any ideas ? Thanks to everybody !

Comment: Is $f(x,t)$ the *marginal* distribution at $t$? To simulate a stochastic process you need the *joint* distribution at all time points (or, perhaps more conveniently, the initial marginal and the transition disitribution).

Comment: I have $\mathbf{P}(X_t \in dx)=f(x,t) \ dx $

Comment: So, indeed, the marginal distribution of $X_t$. In the case of Brownian motion, the joint distribution is relatively simple because increments are independent. Are the increments of $X_t$ independent? Or maybe the $X_t$ themselves are independent? Otherwise, if you don't specify a joint model then you haven't fully specified which stochastic process you're considering by only specifying the marginals.